# Wrong graphs JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am testing on a microservice with cache. The idea of this particular test is to clear the cache once the performance is stable, to see how it gets worse when accessing the database.

The thing is that, as you can see in the terminal logs image, from 2:09 to 6:09 the error is 0%.

At instant 6:09 the cache is cleaned, from there the error % rises until it returns to 0% in the last two readings.

[Terminal logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI5zj.jpg)

Because of this, the graphs should not show errors from 2:09 to 6:09, but this is not the case.

As can be seen in the graph of the response codes per second from 8:54 to 8:59 almost straight lines appear, which should not be the case because there have been no errors. Errors should only appear from 8:52 to 8:54 and from 8:59 onwards.

[Response Codes Per Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vvCt.png)

What is the reason for this? Is it due to granularity? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest stable [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl)

For demo purposes I used [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy):

```
if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long)) < 60000) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
    SampleResult.setResponseCode('500')

}
else if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long)) < 120000) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(true)
    SampleResult.setResponseCode('200')
}

else if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long)) < 180000) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
    SampleResult.setResponseCode('400')
}
```

What it does is:

- During first minute all requests are failing with status code of 500
- During second minute all requests are passing with status code of 200
- During third minute all requests are failing with status code of 400

Summarizer output:

```
./jmeter -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using test.jmx
Starting standalone test @ October 13, 2023 10:50:55 AM CEST (1697187055335)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary +      4 in 00:00:04 =    0.9/s Avg:  1103 Min:  1004 Max:  1399 Err:     4 (100.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary +     29 in 00:00:29 =    1.0/s Avg:  1008 Min:  1005 Max:  1016 Err:    29 (100.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary =     33 in 00:00:34 =    1.0/s Avg:  1020 Min:  1004 Max:  1399 Err:    33 (100.00%)
summary +     30 in 00:00:30 =    1.0/s Avg:  1006 Min:  1002 Max:  1014 Err:    25 (83.33%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary =     63 in 00:01:04 =    1.0/s Avg:  1013 Min:  1002 Max:  1399 Err:    58 (92.06%)
summary +     30 in 00:00:30 =    1.0/s Avg:  1007 Min:  1003 Max:  1016 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary =     93 in 00:01:34 =    1.0/s Avg:  1011 Min:  1002 Max:  1399 Err:    58 (62.37%)
summary +     30 in 00:00:30 =    1.0/s Avg:  1006 Min:  1002 Max:  1012 Err:     5 (16.67%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary =    123 in 00:02:05 =    1.0/s Avg:  1010 Min:  1002 Max:  1399 Err:    63 (51.22%)
summary +     29 in 00:00:29 =    1.0/s Avg:  1007 Min:  1002 Max:  1016 Err:    29 (100.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
summary =    152 in 00:02:34 =    1.0/s Avg:  1009 Min:  1002 Max:  1399 Err:    92 (60.53%)
summary +     26 in 00:00:26 =    1.0/s Avg:  1007 Min:  1003 Max:  1019 Err:    25 (96.15%) Active: 0 Started: 1 Finished: 1
summary =    178 in 00:03:00 =    1.0/s Avg:  1009 Min:  1002 Max:  1399 Err:   117 (65.73%)
Tidying up ...    @ October 13, 2023 10:53:56 AM CEST (1697187236470)
... end of run
```

And chart generated from the .jtl results file using [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) listener accurately shows the response times distribution.

[image]

and the same for [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/):

[image]

So you might look into wrong .jtl file, i.e. having previous stale data.